# XPath expression for content in a node until a node with string is encountered

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, domxpath

I'm looking for an XPath expression to get the article content without the references section. I want everything in the article section until a `<p>` tag occurs, which has a "References" inside it.

```
//root/main/article/following-sibling::p[.="References"]
```

```xml
<root>
    <main>
        <article>
            <p>
               The stunning increase in homelessness announced in Los Angeles 
               this week — up 16% over last year citywide — was an almost  an 
               incomprehensible conundrum given the nation's booming economy 
               and the hundreds of millions of dollars that city, county and 
               state officials have directed toward the problem.
            </p>
            <p>
                "We cannot let a set of difficult numbers discourage us 
                or weaken our resolve" Garcetti said.
            </p>
            <p>
                References: Maeve Reston, CNN
            </p>
        </article>
    </main>
</root>
```

The result I'm looking for would be the following.

```xml
<p>
    The stunning increase in homelessness announced in Los Angeles
    this week — up 16% over last year citywide — was an almost  an
    incomprehensible conundrum given the nation's booming economy
    and the hundreds of millions of dollars that city, county and
    state officials have directed toward the problem.
</p>
<p>
    "We cannot let a set of difficult numbers discourage us
    or weaken our resolve" Garcetti said.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/root/main/article/p[starts-with(normalize-space(),'References')]
                  /preceding-sibling::p
```

will select the paragraphs preceding the one with "References".

You can append `/text()` if you want only the text node children of those `p` elements.